# Prove that $9 \vert (1-10^{i})$ without Mathematical Induction

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

I’m an undergraduate student taking a Discrete Mathematics module. I have a proof question from a past year paper to prove that the digit sum, $s$  of a non-negative integer,$n$ satisfies the following result, $$s \equiv n\ (mod\ 9) $$.

I have approached it initially using a direct proof. A sketch of my proof would be deducing that $s-n$ reduces to $$
\sum_{i=0}^k d_{i}.(1-10^{i})$$, where $k$ is some non-negative integer and $d_{0},d_{1},...,d_{k}$ are the decimal digits of the number $n$. Afterwards, we need to prove that $9 \vert (1-10^{i})$ and by the linear combination property of integers, $9 \vert (s-n)$ which is then equivalent to saying $s \equiv n\ (mod\ 9) $.
 (By the way, $ \vert$, means "is a divisor of", in case this is not a universal notation)

My initial plan to prove this lemma: $9 \vert (1-10^{i})$ is by Mathematical induction, but it looks like this question is supposed to be simple due to the marks awarded, so Mathematical Induction might be an overkill.

Alternatively, I think a result I learnt from tutorial, which is that $9 \vert n \iff 9 \vert s$, might be useful here. However, I don’t know how I could link this result to modular arithmetic. I am also restricted to quoting results from the discrete mathematics textbook:Discrete Mathematics with applications by Susanna S. Epp, without proof, as well as tutorial results. Can someone share how this result might make my proof of the Lemma: $9 \vert (1-10^{i})$ simpler, or is there any other way of making this part simpler besides Mathematical Induction. Thanks.

Comment: I actually do not know, what you have to proof. You have to show, that for a non-negativ number $n$, the digit sum is $s\equiv n\mod 9$. What is $s$ supposed to be?

Comment: In general, any number $n$ can be represented as $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty d_k10^k$$ where $d_k \in \mathbb{Z}, 0\le d_k <10$ for all $k$ and $d_k=0$ for all but finitely many $k$. Then, since $10 = 9+1$, you have $$n= \sum_{k\ge 0}d_k(9+1)^k \equiv \sum_{k\ge 0} d_k 1^k \pmod{9} \equiv \sum_{k\ge 0}d_k \pmod{9} = s$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate $1-10^i \pmod 9$. Notice that you can reduce the number $10 \pmod 9$, since $a^i \equiv b^i$, if $a\equiv b$.

But
$$10^i \equiv 1^i = 1 \pmod 9$$
so what you get is

$$1 - 10^i \equiv 1 - 1 = 0 \pmod 9$$
which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Hi there, actually I could use a theorem from $10^i \equiv 1^i = 1 \pmod 9$ to simplify to $9 \vert (1-10^{I})$, it seems pretty elegant from the way you do things. However, may I question why is there the intentional equal sign after the $\equiv$, that seems abit confusing for me.

Comment: It is because there actually is equality there (one raised to a power equals one). But yep, to be pedantic use $\equiv$ since that is what is needed. It just seems pretty self evident that if numbers are same, they are also congruent :D.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$10^i-1=99999\cdots9.$$

Second hint:

$$99999\cdots9=9\cdot11111\cdots1.$$

Comment: Actually this result was given to me in some other assignment, but I'm not sure whether I need to prove it. Is it rigorous to do so?

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth: if you need rigor, you have to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

Some hints you may find useful:

1. Saying that $9$ divise $(1-10^k)$ is the same that saying $10^k \equiv 1 \pmod 9$.
2. $a\equiv b \pmod c \implies a^k\equiv b^k \pmod c$